# Search method in java "ID not found"

Tags: java

I have some troubles with search method, I tried the code below and he is working, but the problem when an Owner_ID doesn't exist in the database doesn't give me the error msg "Owner not found"?

what am I missing here ?

```
private void search() {

    try {
        int OWNER_ID = Integer.parseInt(this.owneridtxt.getText().trim());
        OwnerRecordDao owndao = new OwnerRecordDao();
        OwnerRecord own = owndao.search(OWNER_ID);
        if (own != null) {               

            companytxt.setText(own.getCOMPANY().toUpperCase());
            addresstxt.setText(own.getADDRESS().toUpperCase());
            citytxt.setText(own.getCITY().toUpperCase());
            statetxt.setText(own.getSTATE().toUpperCase());
            zipcodetxt.setText(Integer.toString(own.getZCODE()));
            phonetxt.setText(own.getPHONE_N());
            regdatetxt.setText(own.getREG_DATE());
        }
        else{
            DM.Message("Owner not found");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    owneridtxt.requestFocus(true);

}

public OwnerRecord search(int OwnerCode) throws Exception {

        OwnerRecord own = new OwnerRecord();

        String sql = "SELECT COMPANY, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZCODE, PHONE_N, REG_DATE FROM OWNER WHERE OWNER_ID = ?";

        DBConnection con = new DBConnection();
        Connection connect = con.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

        try {
            ps.setInt(1, OwnerCode);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                own.setCOMPANY(rs.getString("COMPANY"));
                own.setADDRESS(rs.getString("ADDRESS"));
                own.setCITY(rs.getString("CITY"));
                own.setSTATE(rs.getString("STATE"));
                own.setZCODE(rs.getInt("ZCODE"));
                own.setPHONE_N(rs.getString("PHONE_N"));
                own.setREG_DATE(rs.getString("REG_DATE"));

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                connect.close();
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }

        return own;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`own` is not null because it contains the hash code to whatever `owndao.serach(OWNER_ID)` is returning.

Try returning `null` in the search method if the `OWNER_ID` isn't found.

Comment: I provided the Search method, can you take a look again, please

Comment: Right, so no matter what, search is returning `own` which is an `OwnerRecord` object that's created at the beginning of your method. In order for `own == null` (and thus enter the else statement of the code you originally posted), you have to either 1) return `null` or 2) set `own = null` and return `own` if your search method does not find a valid `OWNER_ID`

Comment: Yeap I got it my friend, I did return the null in search method. and it works, thank you so much

Comment: Great! If this has resolved the question for you, hit that little grey check mark up and to the left!